# Being notified of caught exceptions in Eclipse / Java application

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to be notified of caught exceptions in an eclipse application?

I know that if I start an application using eclipse debugger, I can suspend execution upon caught and uncaught exceptions (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3066280/228965). I guess this feature somehow uses JVMTI.

Now I have the following problem:

I have an eclipse application not written by me. I want to monitor this application. I have written some bundles to monitor different aspect of the application (user interactions, workbench changes, etc..). I start these bundles along the application using bundles.info file. Now I need to be notified whenever an exception happens. I added a listener to error log and this way I am notified of uncaught exceptions. However I want also to be able to be notified of "any" exception, even those that have been caught by the original developers.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Would running that application in Eclipse's debugger work, or do you need a way to automatically log all exceptions from within the program?

Comment: Use AOP to find all throws and add a `before` advice that logs. Not Eclipse-specific.

Comment: I don't have the source code of the program. It is an eclipse application. I start my bundles inside the OSGi runtime of it and want to be notified upon different events, for example an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint to the constructors of `java.lang.Exception` (or maybe even `Throwable`, depending upon exactly what you're looking for).

All exceptions, even custom ones, must extend from one of these, so you can find each Exception as it is being created - and then even trace it through to see where it is being caught and handled (if at all).

Using AOP may also be a good option, but this approach doesn't require any modifications to the existing code - source code or byte code.

Comment: I am not running the program from within eclipse or in debug mode. I have given an eclipse application, and I start my own bundles in OSGi runtime of that application. There is no debugging and breakpoint.

Comment: Is there any possibility to run it in debug mode?  (You don't need Eclipse for this.)  If you can't do this, then you're pretty much looking to modify the code - in which case I would suggest the AOP approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate the logger of your application. If it use log4j, you could create an appender specific for exceptions and work with them.

Answer (score -1):

From JDK 1.5 you can use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` for exactly this purpose.

Comment: From the question: 'However I want also to be able to be notified of "any" exception, even those that have been caught by the original developers.' Your solution only handles uncaught exceptions.