# App which is installed on device not showing up in the app menu

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run an eye detection app on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. When I run the app it says the following in the console window:

```
[2013-04-08 14:24:16 - EyeDetect] Performing sync
[2013-04-08 14:24:20 - EyeDetect] Uploading EyeDetect.apk onto device 'c16070a0ffe3c9f'
[2013-04-08 14:24:20 - EyeDetect] Installing EyeDetect.apk...
[2013-04-08 14:24:23 - EyeDetect] Success!
[2013-04-08 14:24:23 - EyeDetect] \EyeDetect\bin\EyeDetect.apk installed on device
[2013-04-08 14:24:23 - EyeDetect] Done!
```

However the app doesn't show in the app menu on the Android device. It does however, appear in the list of applications under `settings>application>manage applications`.

So it appears to be among the applications installed on the device, but I can't figure out how to run the app. I really need your help.

Also I can't debug the app as the debug perspective doesn't show up.

Comment: What kind of app are you running ? For instance, wallpapers app aren't visible in the app menu. I think one of your activites have to have an intent filter in the manifest like this : 
`            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>` which tells Android that this activity can be launched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android app will not launch on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418949/android-app-will-not-launch-on-device)

Answer (score 3):

1.Check where intent-filter is located!

2.Check if exist duplicate  </intent filter>, if exist remove one.

3.And inside of intent-filter inner atributes like <data android:mimeType="image/*/>

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    //Remove        <!--<data android:mimeType="image/*" />-->
```

4. Foreach inner intent-filter atribute you may sure that you know why they're there.

Comment: I had a "data android:scheme" attribute under intent-filter; as soon as I removed it and did a rebuild and install, I could see the installed app in my apps launch list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

If the application was previously installed and not getting installed again, then from the command prompt run "adb uninstall" package name

On the phone Settings -> Application -> Development -> Debuggable to true

Try installing the app from the command prompt adb install apk.file

Restart the device: Restarting the phone & eclipse

Comment: and while you are at it unplug the battery then plug it back in, hit the enter key 5 times and chant "Demons be gone!". Works every time.

Answer (score 0):

An eye detection app might be a new functionality, which would appear under settings. For eg. when you install wallpapers and keyboards, they are in settings>application>manage applications but they don't appear as an application on the screen as they don't have an intent filter, as pointed out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the behavior of an application when there is no manifest. If you haven't defined any application in your manifest or launcher activity Android will just go "ok, hey thanks for the APK, I don't know what to do with it." and so you won't see any launcher because it can't launch your app.

Answer (score 0):

While taking the apk there may be some slight mistakes in manifest file. These wont show as any error but can view in console page. Please check and verify before taking apk.

In my case, the closing tag for an element was missing in manifest file. However  I could make the apk and managed to install in a device successfully.

This can't  view in app listing page but  While searching inside settings page, inside the apps listing it is existing.

Further re-installing also restricted in such scenario. Later I needed to manually uninstall this app from settings page.