# Plugin for better debugging in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am new to this project and it's code doesn't have any logger statement. It is tedious and time consuming  to follow any flow.
Because of the application's exception handling framework all the exception fall into a common exception block and it is pretty cumbersome to track back from there.
Is there any Eclipse plugin which can help me to debug the issues? I am kind of looking for similar to XCode's debug feature where it stops the flow at the line which is causing exception. You can track back on that.

Updated my question.

Note: I am using Eclipse Juno and in the middle of developing AspectJ logging utility to help me with debug statements.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint for all XYZException, Eclipse debug plugin will halt at the exception catched.

Comment: Does the code have source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Himanshu, Eclipse has a full-fledged debugger which has withstood the test of time. You will need to give it a bit more time and explore it to realize it's full potential.

For instance, the feature that you miss from XCode has a counterpart in Eclipse in the form of Exception Breakpoints.

Setting them up (as Ajay George points out) is detailed in this question :
[Break when exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown)

I am very interested in knowing the other things that you are looking for in the Eclipse Debugger.

**Edit** : The following might not be of great help to you if you already have experience with Eclipse but I shall leave them here for posterity :
**[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)** is a comprehensive tutorial on debugging with Eclipse.

Also, if you prefer watching and doing instead of reading then **[this](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html)** is a good place to start ( OR directly checkout/download the videos from **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsetutorial/files/3.%20Debugger%20Tutorial/Version%201.0/)** )

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has an inbuilt debugger to debug java programs (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/), are you looking for something other than this?

Comment: Yes I know about it. But looking for something better.