# How can I make Eclipse to break on ALL uncaught exceptions?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I am writing a Java program using Eclipse Juno.

When I run the program, and it meets an exception, program just dies with back trace. I set these exception breakpoint to debug at time for any unexpected exceptions.

- `Exception`
- `Throwable`
- `Error`

but, anyway, still I see some uncaught exceptions just makes program crashes instead of breaks by Eclipse. I want to break for any uncaught exceptions. But I can't find option to choose ALL exceptions. How can I make Eclipse to break on any exceptions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally I found it!

I had to explicitly set *subclasses of this exception* checkbox for each exception in *Breakpoints* pane.

Also, I need to set `NullPointerException`'s caught locations too or even uncaught exceptions won't be caught.

[image]

Comment: Why do you declare multiple exception breakpoints? Throwable should be enough with the subclasses option selected.

Comment: @Bananeweizen I didn't know that when I capturing the picture. And you're right about subclassing.

Answer (score 7):

You need to Go to `Breakpoints` view > `Add Java Exception Breakpoint`  then search for `Throwable` it will come up with `java.lang.Throwable`. Add `java.lang.Throwable` and check `Subclasses of this exception` just as @Eonil did.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. **Window->Show View->Other**
   [image: 1]
2. **Search for breakpoints which appears Debug->Breakpoints**
   [image: 2]
3. **Now add Throwable Exception by pressing `J!` icon**
   [image: 3]
4. **Add Exception**
   [image: 4]