# Java unknown exceptions

Tags: java, swing, exception, illegalargumentexception

Can anyone please tell me why I get the following exceptions

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException adding a window to a container :
 java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source) 
 java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)  
 java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)         
 javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 clockframe.<init>(clockframe.java:14)
 clockframe.main(clockframe.java:32)
```

My code which is inside clockpanel.java file is below: I am beginner so I don't know how to work this out......

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class clockframe extends JFrame
    {
      public clockframe()
      {
        super("Clock");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(225, 125);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        clockpanel time = new clockpanel();
        add(time);
        setVisible(true);
      }

      private void setLookAndFeel()
      {
         try
         {
             UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
         }
         catch (Exception exc)
         {
             // ignore error
         }
      }

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
          clockframe clock = new clockframe();
      }

}
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, having configured it to break on exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown

Comment: Start your class names with a capital letter

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I'd guess `clockpanel` is actually a frame.  But I don't like guessing.  2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 2):

`clockpanel` probably extends a window such as `JFrame`. You probably meant to extend `JPanel` instead (although doing so is not necessary unless adding new functionality such as custom painting to the new `JPanel`).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JFrame documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29)

```
IllegalArgumentException - if index is invalid 
IllegalArgumentException - if adding the container's parent to itself 
IllegalArgumentException - if adding a window to a container
```

It is looking likely that `clockpanel` inherits from `Window` thus triggering the last clause.

Edit: no need to guess any more.. just noticed the top of your stack trace.. this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Answer lies it self in stack trace :

```
 thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException adding a window to a container
```

You are adding `window` to `container`, which is not allowed.