# eclipse debugger - breakpoint when exception is thrown on a specific place

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Is it possible to break execution in the debugger of eclipse when exception is thrown on a specific line or in a specific class?

Globally we can break when exception is thrown easily: [Break when exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't try that, but when you click on "Breakpoint Properties" there is Filtering tab also, where you can specify locations, when stop or do not stop on the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to break the execution in the debugger of eclipse. Only the exceptions thrown (checked and unchecked exceptions) will be able to break the execution.

You can add the class name in 'Class load breakpoint' to enable to debugger. To enable 'Class load breakpoint' Navigate to Eclipse - Menu - Run - Add Class Load Breakpoint - Add your class name. Refer the snapshot below

[image: Add Class Load Breakpoint]

In case of any specific line in a class you have to manually break the execution using terminate button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think  Class Load Breakpoint is what I was looking for.