# out of memory when running agents

Tags: java, lotus-notes

When I run certain agents, in which I recycle my objects I sometimes get this message when running the agents:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3580)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:104)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:164)
    at lotus.domino.ClassHashtable.explodeArchive(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.ClassHashtable.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
```

How can I find out in which agent or which object this memory gets full?
And how can I empty the memory again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "empty the memory again", and without a thorough review of all of your code nobody here is going to be able to help you find the source of your leak. You may want to review this [answer to an older question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak) for ideas about how to try and track down your leak.

Of course, in Domino agents the most common issue is non-recycled objects, so although you say you are recycling I'd look for any possible branches in which you may be missing a recycle() call. Or, I'd consider using the [OpenNTF Domino API](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API) instead of the standard API, as it eliminates the need to make recycle() calls.

Comment: I have no idea how to install the openNTF Domino API, could you maybe please explain this.

Comment: The people who are working on the OpenNTF Domino API have explained it here: https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/wiki/Using-the-API:-Agents

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can stop you debug when the exception is thrown:

[Break when exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/break-when-exception-is-thrown)